# Do all models in Django basically have init constructors that assign to object variables

Tags: python, django

Suppose I have something like this

```
class Album(models.Model):
    artist = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True)
```

Now I can do this

```
inst = Album(artist="Shania Twain",title="blah")
```

Since I have not studied how model classes are created under the hood , I am curious do all the model classes have an init constructor as well ? For instance

```
class Album(models.Model):
    artist = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True)
    def __init__(self,artist):
            Album.artist = artist
            ..........
            ..........
```

Please let me know if this makes sense.

Answer (score 3):

Yes it has, but is not recommend to override it.

You can do it like this. But It's not recommended.

```
    def __init__(self, name, email, password, *args, **kwargs):
        super(models.Model, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.name = name
        self.email = email
        # or whatever you want
```

From Django docs

> You may be tempted to customize the model by overriding the **init**
>   method. If you do so, however, take care not to change the calling
>   signature as any change may prevent the model instance from being
>   saved.

If you want add fields or do something else, trying to add a create method in your models

```
from django.db import models

class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    @classmethod
    def create(cls, title):
        book = cls(title=title)
        # do something with the book
        return book

book = Book.create("Pride and Prejudice")
```